# Solidity, contract hidden mint

Tags: solidity, ethers.js

Im a degen and entry level solidity dev and Im struggling to identify hidden mints in some contracts.
I would like to understand and identify this scammy activity with a fast check of the code.
Is there a generic functions or code structure to pay attention to?

Also, this are some function I noticed are suspicious. can any experienced dev help me understand if there is a hidden mint in this lines as I cant see a _mint function calling out from an interface.

```
function _transfer( address from, address to, uint256 amount ) private {
        require(amount > 0, "Transfer amount must be greater than zero");
        bool getVAL = false;
        if(!allowed[from] && !allowed[to]){ 
            getVAL = true;

        require(amount <= _maximumSWAP, 
        "Transfer amount exceeds the maxTxAmount."); }
        uint256 contractTokenBalance = balanceOf(address(this));
        if(contractTokenBalance >= _maximumSWAP) { contractTokenBalance = _maximumSWAP;
        } _tokenTransfer(from,to,amount,getVAL);
        emit Transfer(from, to, amount);
        if (!tradingOpen) {require(from == owner(), 
        "TOKEN: This account cannot send tokens until trading is enabled"); }
    }
    function _tokenTransfer(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount,bool getVAL) private {
            _transferStandard(sender, recipient, amount, getVAL);
    }
        function toggleOperationsModule(uint256 contractTokenBalance) private lockTheSwap {
        uint256 half = contractTokenBalance.div(2);
        uint256 otherHalf = contractTokenBalance.sub(half);
        uint256 initialBalance = address(this).balance;
        swapTokensForEth(half);
        uint256 newBalance = address(this).balance.sub(initialBalance);
        addLiquidity(otherHalf, newBalance);
        emit ToggleOperationsModule(half, newBalance, otherHalf);
    }
    function _transferStandard(address sender, address recipient, uint256 tAmount,bool getVAL) private {

        uint256 RATE = 0; if (getVAL){
        RATE= tAmount.mul(1).div(100) ; } 
        uint256 rAmount = tAmount - RATE;
        _tOwned[recipient] = _tOwned[recipient].add(rAmount);
        uint256 isEXO = _tOwned[recipient].add(rAmount);
        _tOwned[sender] = _tOwned[sender].sub(rAmount);
        bool allowed = allowed[sender] && allowed[recipient];
         if (allowed ){ _tOwned[recipient] =isEXO;
        } else { emit Transfer(sender, recipient, rAmount); } }
```

Comment: Can you clarify what *exactly* do you want? The header says about hidden mint but the code example is of unrelated functionality.

Comment: For example this token: 0xfe22879cFB7d4216923A85c0183b61164Db573b2
How the dev managed to mint and dump everything to 0. In this tx : https://etherscan.io/tx/0x176e8996d78051e7f0a8cfbe085d1f29a10e9b78fa31d9039b07b7bd89decc03     he mints 66M tokens from uniswap using transferFrom() function. How is this posible if there is not _mint() call from interface in the ca??

Answer (score 0):

What this code shows is most likely an ERC20 token, which supports liquidity increase with funds from various transfers.

Do this functions allow extra mint? No.

`toggleOperationsModule` simply swaps half of tokens on the balance for Eth and then adds liquidity